# Selecting most recent row/event per day plus latest known IDs

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
ID  StatusID1 StatusID2  StatusID3  StatusID4  EventDateTime
1     1         -1         -1         NULL     2020-04-17 17:39:35.0660000
1     1         -1         -1          2       2020-04-17 18:39:35.0660000
1     1         -1         -1         NULL     2020-04-17 19:39:35.0660000
1     1          1         -1         NULL     2020-04-17 13:39:35.0660000
1     1          -1        -1         NULL     2020-04-18 10:39:35.0660000
1     1          1         -1          3       2020-04-18 12:39:35.0660000
1     2          2          3         NULL     2020-04-18 16:39:35.0660000
1     1          1         -1         NULL     2020-04-18 14:39:35.0660000
```

I need this to output the latest for each day as:

```
ID  StatusID1 StatusID2  StatusID3  StatusID4  EventDateTime
1     1          1            3           2     2020-04-17 19:39:35.0660000
1     2          2            3           3     2020-04-18 16:39:35.0660000
```

There will be multiple IDs per day. I'll ultimately add a dateid instead of the datetime using CONVERT(varchar(8), EventDateTime, 112).

I need the latest StatusID1 of the day.
I need the latest known StatusID2 across dates. -1 is unknown, but it may change over time. I need the latest non -1 for each date.
StatusID3 will never change, once known, so can be changed retroactively.
StatusID4 can change, so the most recent known.

Think of:
StatusID as the current state of the application,
StatusID2 as age.
StatusID3 as gender (assume it won't change during the process).
StatusID4 is the employee handling the case.

Current code:

```
SELECT
t2.ID,
CASE WHEN t3.ID is NULL THEN 1 
WHEN t3.ID IS NOT NULL THEN 2 
ELSE -1 END as StatusID1,
t5.ID as StatusID2,
t5.ID2 as StatusID3,
t1.ID as StatusID4,
COALESCE(t2.datetime, t1.datetime) as EventDateTime,
CONVERT(varchar(8), COALESCE(t2.datetime, t1.datetime), 112) as DateID
From t1
'Joining tables t2 to t5'
```

I need to group by max of EventDateTime, picking up the latest known values for StatusID4 per day, StatusID3 going back as well as future, StatusID2 latest known per day.

Can anyone give any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, SQL Server does not support `IGNORE NULL`s anywhere -- and that would make this both more concise and more efficient.

You can do this using `outer apply`:

```
select dte, i1.id1, i2.id2, i3.id3, i4.id4
from (select distinct convert(date, eventdatetime) as dte
      from t
     ) t outer apply
     (select top (1) t2.id1
      from t t2
      where id1 <> -1 and convert(date, t2.eventdatetime) = t.dte
      order by t2.eventdatetime desc
     ) i1 outer apply
     (select top (1) t2.id2
      from t t2
      where id2 <> -1 and convert(date, t2.eventdatetime) = t.dte
      order by t2.eventdatetime desc
     ) i2 outer apply
     (select top (1) t2.id3
      from t t2
      where id3 <> -1 and convert(date, t2.eventdatetime) = t.dte
      order by t2.eventdatetime desc
     ) i3 outer apply
     (select top (1) t2.id4
      from t t2
      where id4 <> -1 and convert(date, t2.eventdatetime) = t.dte
      order by t2.eventdatetime desc
     ) i4 ;
```